# How do I declare an attribute in Python without a value?

Tags: python, class

In C# I would go:

```
string UserName;
string Password;
```

But now, in Python:

```
class User:
    UserName
    Password
```

I receive an error that `UserName` isn't defined. Can I not declare a variable without a variable?

Comment: The Python tutorial is here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html It's pretty good if you have done programming before.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

In Python, and many other languages, there is a value that means "no value". In Python, that value is `None`.  So you could do something like this:

```
class User:
   username = None
   password = None
```

Those sure sound like instance variables though, and not class variables, so maybe do this:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.username = None
        self.password = None
```

Note how Python assigns the `None` value implicitly from time to time:

```
def f():
    pass
g = f() # g now has the value of None
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. A couple of questions though, why do you put (object) at the end of the class name? Also, what is def __init__ ? If you have a good link that'll be great.

Comment: @Sergio Tapia: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python

Comment: extending `object` in Python is kind of a syntactic hack, though an extremely common one, that means you want to use new-style classes. If using Python 2.x, you should get in the habit of doing that.  `__init__` is a python constructor.

Comment: `__init__` is Python's constructor method.  It takes `self` as its first parameter, which is a reference to the object to be created, as well as a variable number of other parameters.  You then construct the object by manipulating `self`.

Comment: Just another quick question. Class variables will be things that only my class uses, correct, like if I have a class for DB connection, the connectionstring will only be useful for itself. But instance classes are items that you want to be available if the class is instantiated, correct?

Comment: @SergioTapia yes. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

Comment: When I am using such practice (declaring object variables with None in __init__ method I get a warning from 'pydev' interpreter saying: "Statement appear to have no effect", so is it a wrong warning?

Comment: @Triptych Python definitely doesn't assign None value "from time to time". If a function/method doesn't contain a `return` statement, then it _always_ returns `None`. I know I am ~10 years late with this comment, but maybe it'll still be useful to someone.

Answer (score 16):

First of all, you should rewrite like this:

```
class User(object):
  def __init__(self, username, password):
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
```

This way, username and password are instance variables instead of class variables (in your example, they are class variables -- all instance variables need to be defined in `__init__` as properties of `self`).  Then, you can initialize a `User` with whatever username and password you want, including `None` if you truly want them to have no value.

Comment: And, if you think you want to "declare" an attribute, you can't.  You can, however, assign `None` so that you can create an attribute.

Answer (score 12):

[Dataclasses for python 3.7+](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html):

```py
@dataclass
class User:
    UserName: str
    Password: str
```

Answer (score 10):

In your code:

```
class User:
    UserName
    Password
    print(UserName, Password)
```

`UserName` and `Password` and `print(UserName, Password)` are parsed as expressions. Since they have not been assigned at this point, you get a `NameError`.

In Python, a variable must be defined with a assignment statement before it can be used in an expression, otherwise you get a NameError. Note that "before" here means "execution order", not "source code order". There's a bit more to it (import statements, globals, namespace hacks), but let's keep it simple here.

The idiomatic way to define a variable "without a value" is to assign it the value `None`.

Also, your code looks like it really wants instance members, and not class members. The idiomatic way to do it, as recognized by some static analysis tools such as `pylint`, is:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.username = None
        self.password = None
```

Also, it is good Python style to derive all classes from "object", so you use new-style classes, and to name instance variable with the lowercase_with_underscore or initialLowerWithCaps convention. The InitialCaps style is quite universally reserved to class names.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. In Python, "Variables" are just names. A name always points ("is bound") to an object. It's convention to assign names that don't yet have a sensible value, but should be present, to `None`.

You might also be interested in my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055029/why-cant-python-handle-true-false-values-as-i-expect/2055144#2055144).

Comment: +1. Always good to remind folks that "assigning value" in Python is a bit of a dubious concept.

Answer (score 3):

Just assign the value of `None`:

`self.username = None`

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But the answer has already been selected.

Comment: It helps to speak positively. When in doubt, run the simplest test to get confirmation.  You can (and may) continue to get upvotes long after an answer was accepted.

Comment: Thanks for pushing S.Lott. I've tested it and updated my answer.