# True = False == True

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't Python handle true/false values as I expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055029/why-cant-python-handle-true-false-values-as-i-expect)

*False = True should raise an error in this case.*

```
False = True
True == False
True
```

*True + False == True?*

```
if True +  False:
    print True
True
```

*True Again?*

```
if str(True + False) + str(False + False) == '10':
    print True
True
```

*LOL*

```
if True + False + True * (False * True ** True / True - True % True) - (True / True) ** True + True - (False ** True ** True):
    print True, 'LOL'
True LOL
```

why this is all True?

Comment: because these are converted to True => 1 and False => 0 in the process? Im not familiar with the Python but some languages just emulate these as constants to byte/int/(bit?).

Comment: In Python 3, this is not possible.

Comment: You can check the discussion about True == 1 at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-guaranteed-by-t

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`False` is just a global variable, you can assign to it. It will, however, break just about everything if you do so.

Note that this behavior has been removed in python3k

```
Python 3.1 (r31:73578, Jun 27 2009, 21:49:46) 
>>> False = True
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: assignment to keyword
```

also, `int(False)` == 0 and `int(True)` == 1, so you can do arbitrary arithmetic with them

Comment: Since True and False are integers, in Python 2.x and 3.x, there is no need to convert them: `False == 0` and `True == 1`.

Comment: No, they're not. They're bools which happen to be easily castable to integers. Try "True is 1" if you don't believe me.

Comment: @KirkStrauser: You should try `isinstance(True, int)`: it is True. I did not write that `True is 1`, only that True is an integer (through inheritance).

Answer (score 7):

See [Why can't Python handle true/false values as I expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055029/why-cant-python-handle-true-false-values-as-i-expect), that will answer your first question. Basically you can think of:

```
False = True
True == False
True
```

as

```
var = True
True == var
True
```

(reminds me of `#define TRUE FALSE // Happy debugging suckers` *chuckles*)

As for the other questions, when you do arithmetic operations on `True` and `False` they get converted to `1` and `0`.

- `True +  False` is the same as `1 + 0`, which is `1`, which is `True`.
- `str(True + False) + str(False + False)` is the same as `str(1) + str(0)`, and the `+` here concatenates strings, so you'll get `10`
- Your last one is a bunch of arithmetic operations that give a non-zero result (1), which is True.

Comment: In C, you need to write `typedef enum {TRUE, FALSE} BOOL;` to keep it subtle ;-)