# True=False assignment in Python 2.x

Tags: python, boolean, keyword, python-2.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t Python handle true/false values as I expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055029/why-cant-python-handle-true-false-values-as-i-expect)

Seems a stupid question, but why is the following statement in Python not explicitly forbidden?

```
>> True=False
>> True
False
```

How is `True` and `False` handled by Python interpreter?

Comment: This is not stupid in the slightest!

Answer (score 6):

`True`, just like `str` or any other builtin, is just a name that exists in the scope by default. You can rebind it like any other such name.

Comment: Actually the OP creates `__main__.True`. `__builtin__.True` is still accessible

Comment: `None = 42` results in a `SyntaxError`. Why doesn't the same logic apply to that name?

Comment: @martineau: it does apply. True/False are keywords in Python 3. btw, you can assign to None in Python 2.3

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I don't think you answered my question (which was directed @wRAR anyway). If `None` is just another name, why can't I assign some other value to it as is possible with the names `True` and `str`?

Comment: @martineau: [`None`, `True`, `False` are keywords](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) in Python 3 so you can't rebind them any more. But historically you could: `None` -- before Python 2.4 (`None` was special constant before Python 3.0), `True/False` -- before Python 3.0. `str` is just another name, you can rebind it.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: OK, so what I think you're saying is that in Python 2.7 `None` is a "special constant" which apparently is effectively the same being a keyword with respect to assigning a new value to it.

Answer (score 2):

Python actually has very few [reserved words](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords). All the rest are subject to redefinition. It's up to you to be careful!

Comment: Question was about 2.7, but just sayin' that in 3.x `True` and `False` are included as reserved words and CANNOT be defined.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> True = False
False
```

In the above assignment, `True` is just a variable like any other variable you use.
Its scope is limited to the current scope. So you can assign any values to it like in the below example. Note that the comparison `2 < 3` still prints `True`, because you have still access to `builtin`.

```
>>> True = 3
>>> True
3
>>> 2 < 3
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Typing

```
True = False
```

you create a new variable called True, which value you assign to False.

Answering your second question, True and False are customized versions of integers 1 and 0 (technically speaking, subclasses), which just have a different string representation.