# Python 3: __builtins__.None: Invalid syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm exploring the REPL and I noticed the `__builtins__` module.

I entered

```
>>> __builtins__.
```

and hit Tab, then Python REPL showed me a list of builtin **identifiers**, including `abs`, `len`, `zip` and `True`, `False`, `None` etc.

The first test passed without doubt:

```
>>> __builtins__.zip is zip
True
```

But the second one didn't:

```
>>> __builtins__.None is None
   File "<stdin>", line 1
    __builtins__.None is None
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can observe this change in the language from the keywords list of [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords). `False`, `None` and `True` were added as keywords to avoid confusion should someone e.g. try to overwrite one of them.

```
>>> False=True
>>> False
True
```

This is valid, but highly misleading, Python 2. Python 3 responds differently:

```
>>> False=True
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to keyword
```

The History of Python has a writeup on [the story of None, True and False](http://python-history.blogspot.se/2013/11/story-of-none-true-false.html).
Here's another [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050815/why-were-true-and-false-changed-to-keywords-in-python-3) on the topic. Another effect of this change is that the compiler knows precisely which objects they are, and doesn't need a namespace lookup when they're referenced.

Python 2:

```
>>> dis.dis(compile("True","foo.py","eval"))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (True)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Python 3:

```
>>> dis.dis(compile("True","foo.py","eval"))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (True)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 6):

`None` is a keyword. As such, it can not be used with the dot notation, much like how `__builtins__.True`, `__builtins__.class` and `__builtins__.def` are also a syntax error.

This can be bypassed by using `getattr`:

```
print(getattr(__builtins__, 'None') is None)
# True
print(getattr(__builtins__, 'False') is False)
# True
print(getattr(__builtins__, 'True') is True)
# True
```

Unlike `abs`, `len`, `zip` etc (which are top-level functions), `None`, `True` and `False` are keywords in Python 3 (see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).

In Python 2 `True` and `False` were not keywords (just a built-in name/constant) (See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) so you could reassign to them. As mentioned above this is impossible in Python 3 since they became keywords.

Also see this question: [True=False assignment in Python 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401563/true-false-assignment-in-python-2-x)

With that said, one can still mess around with `__builtins__.True` in Python 3, but it will not affect the actual `True` as it used to be in Python 2:

```
print(getattr(__builtins__, 'True'))
# True
setattr(__builtins__, 'True', False)
print(getattr(__builtins__, 'True'))
# False
print(True)
# True
```

Comment: `class` and `def` **do not** show up in the list when I hit Tab after entering `__builtins__.`.

Comment: @iBug why does it matter? for what it's worth, `True` and `False` do show up but still cause a syntax error

Comment: Neither `class` nor `def` are names bound to objects. Keywords and names are two different sets; their intersection includes `None`, `True` and `False`.

Comment: But then, why are None, True and False in the __builtins__ module?

Comment: @steffen I assume it's in case someone wrote code that expects them to be there (perhaps as part of some weird 2.x backwards-compatibility patch, although I can't imagine offhand how it would actually solve a practical problem). I can't imagine that they'd be included if Python were redesigned from scratch today.