# Why were True and False changed to keywords in Python 3

Tags: python, keyword

In Python 2, we could reassign `True` and `False` (but not `None`), but all three (`True`, `False`, and `None`) were considered builtin variables.  However, in Py3k all three were changed into keywords as per [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html).

From my own speculation, I could only guess that it was to prevent shenanigans like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055029/why-cant-python-handle-true-false-values-as-i-expect) which derive from the old `True, False = False, True` prank.  However, in Python 2.7.5, and perhaps before, statements such as `None = 3` which reassigned `None` raised `SyntaxError: cannot assign to None`.

Semantically, I don't believe `True`, `False`, and `None` are keywords, since they are at last semantically literals, which is what Java has done.  I checked PEP 0 (the index) and I couldn't find a PEP explaining why they were changed.

Are there performance benefits or other reasons for making them keywords as opposed to literals or special-casing them like `None` in python2?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Possibly because Python 2.6 not only allowed `True = False` but also allowed you to say funny things like:

```
__builtin__.True = False
```

which would reset `True` to `False` for the entire process.  It can lead to really funny things happening:

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>> __builtin__.True = False
>>> True
False
>>> False
False
>>> __builtin__.False = True
>>> True
False
>>> False
False
```

*EDIT*: As pointed out by [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77939/mike), the [Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python3.0) also states the following under *Core Language Changes*:

- Make True and False keywords.

  - Reason: make assignment to them impossible.

Comment: Wouldn't shenanigans like this still be stopped if `True` and `False` were like `None` instead of keywords?  `>>> __builtin__.None = 5
SyntaxError: cannot assign to None`

Comment: Partial restrictions on `None` have existed since 2.6.

Comment: So if `True` and `False` were changed to be None-esque instead of keywords, it would work too, right?

Comment: It seems that there was a [time](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-January/005284.html) when they didn't want `True` and `False` to be reserved words, but apparently it changed :)

Comment: +1; according to the [python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python3.0) it was to "make assignment to them impossible".

Comment: @Mike the question is why they chose to make them keywords, instead of making them immutable (a la None in py26+)

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee The move to make None a constant was temporary.  See http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2004-July/046294.html

Comment: Can't you still do `setattr(__builtin__, "False", True)`?

Comment: @Mehrdad Did you mean `setattr(builtins, "False", True)` instead? That doesn't work in python 3.x.

Comment: @devnull: Ah yeah sure. It's not a syntax error though, my point is that making `True` and `False` keywords doesn't "prevent" assignment to them in any way that lets you avoid runtime checks... you still need checks for these situations.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Even if you try `setattr(builtins, 'False', True)`, the expression `False` won't look up `builtins.False` for its value. The `False` keyword refers directly to the `False` object, not the value of an attribute in the builtins module.

Answer (score 12):

For two reasons, mainly:

1. So people don't do a `__builtin__.True = False` prank hidden on a random module. (as explained by devnull)
2. Because keywords are faster than global builtins. In Python 2.x, the interpreter would have to resolve those variables' values before using them, which is a bit slower than keywords. (see [Why is if True slower than if 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123965/why-if-true-is-slower-than-if-1))

Answer (score 4):

This was discussed some months ago on python-dev. 
Having tons of links to the definition of True would be annoying, contrary to links to e.g. the nonlocal or with statements doc.

And things I conclude why True and False will make things "even finer".

1. re-bound as a side effect of functions called within the loop.

   It's really easy to change True, such as:

   `def True():
       print True`
2. There is really no good use case for letting user code rebind the built-in names None, True, and False, making them keywords has almost only pluses.
3. Make program has to look-up "True" in symbol-table at each step just to find True has value True is far from intuitive. (that is why 1 is faster than True.)

   > x=compile('while 1: foop()', '', 'exec')
   >
   > dis.dis(x)

   ```
         0 SETUP_LOOP              19 (to 22)
         3 JUMP_FORWARD             4 (to 10)
         6 JUMP_IF_FALSE           11 (to 20)
         9 POP_TOP
   >>   10 LOAD_NAME                0 (foop)
        13 CALL_FUNCTION            0
        16 POP_TOP
        17 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
   >>   20 POP_TOP
        21 POP_BLOCK
   >>   22 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
        25 RETURN_VALUE
   ```

> x=compile('while True: foop()', '', 'exec')
>
> dis.dis(x)

```
          0 SETUP_LOOP              19 (to 22)
    >>    3 LOAD_NAME                0 (True)
          6 JUMP_IF_FALSE           11 (to 20)
          9 POP_TOP
         10 LOAD_NAME                1 (foop)
         13 CALL_FUNCTION            0
         16 POP_TOP
         17 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
    >>   20 POP_TOP
         21 POP_BLOCK
    >>   22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         25 RETURN_VALUE
```

### reference:

- http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-checkins/2011-September/107641.html
- http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-checkins/2012-January/110353.html
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.lang.python/False$20True$20keyword/comp.lang.python/65B6qWUf8wI/HwQ5pwnW7woJ

### Beginning talk related to assigning to True and False:

- http://bugs.python.org/issue2349
- https://groups.google.com/forum/comp.lang.python/65B6qWUf8wI/HwQ5pwnW7woJ

## some Aux Data:

### PS: some number shows True/1:

```
[alex@lancelot test]$ timeit.py -c -s'import itertools as it' 'c=it.count()'
'while True:' '  if c.next()>99: break'
10000 loops, best of 3: 91 usec per loop

[alex@lancelot test]$ timeit.py -c -s'import itertools as it' 'c=it.count()'
'while 1:' '  if c.next()>99: break'
10000 loops, best of 3: 76 usec per loop
```