# Int is not a keyword, What happens if we use it as a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, variables, int

Int is not a keyword in python, and hence can be used as a variable name.
I tried to assign a string into the name and it worked.

I did this in the IDLE of Python3.8.2

```
>>> a = int(4.5)
>>> print(a)
4
>>> int = 'abc'
>>> print(int)
abc
>>> b = int(5.7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    b = int(5.7)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>> print(b)
```

the code works without the last part.
ie from b = int(5.7)

Why does it happen?
and shouldn't int be a keyword?
how can we fix it keeping the existing code intact as if working in the console?

I tried using the del keyword and it worked. but I don't know why.

```
>>> del int
>>> b = int(5.7)
>>> print(b)
5
```

This works.

Please explain. :)

Comment: It seems that some names are not keywords. int and str are two examples.

Comment: Because `int` is just a variable, which refers to the built-in class `int`. Just like if you do `class Foo: pass` then you can do `Foo = 'a string'`. Classes, functions etc are first-class objects like any other in Python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't data types like int keywords in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678738/why-arent-data-types-like-int-keywords-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the basic types are keywords, they are type objects

```
>>> type(int)
<class 'type'>
```

and they create instances of their class when used

```
>>> type(int('100'))
<class 'int'>
```

They work like classes you define yourself

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
... 
>>> type(Foo)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(Foo())
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

The only difference is that they are in the "builtins" namespace, but due to python's scoping rule, "builtins" is check last. Any variable you create is in a namespace checked before builtins so shadows the builtin itself.

As for why, just about everything in python is a first class object and they all follow the same rules. There is no special code or any special rules for `int` (other than its implementation) - it works the same as any other class.

Namespaces are hierarchical, mostly builtins --> module --> local meaning that local shadows module which shadows builtins. `del` removes a variable from a namespace, removing that shadow. If you create a variable called `int` and then `del int`, python will no longer find it in the local namespace and will fall back to the original.

Of course, you can always mess things up on a more permanent basis if you wish:

```
>>> __builtins__.__dict__['int'] = float
>>> int(1)
1.0
```

Comment: And to *restore* the value of `int` to the builtin value, just do `del int`

Comment: @dawg - Right! I'll add a note about that.