# Python Boolean Logic Confusion

Tags: python, python-2.7, boolean, boolean-logic

Can someone clarify the logic behind these assignment statements.

```
>>> True
True
>>> True = False
>>> True
False
>>> True = True
>>> True
False
>>> a = True
>>> if a:
...     print "a is True"
... else:
...     print "a is False"
...
a is False
```

According to the manual, the only two instances of class bool is `True` and `False`.

```
Help on bool object:

True = class bool(int)
 |  bool(x) -> bool
 |
 |  Returns True when the argument x is true, False otherwise.
 |  The builtins True and False are the only two instances of the class bool.
 |  The class bool is a subclass of the class int, and cannot be subclassed.
 |
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      bool
 |      int
 |      object
```

So am I overriding the default instance? And if so, why does python does not assign `True` to is default instance in the below assignment? How can I assign the default python `True` in the below statement?

```
>>> True = False
>>> True
False
>>> True = True
>>> True
False     #why?
```

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Comment: Python 3 tag is irrelevant here: [Why were True and False changed to keywords in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050815/why-were-true-and-false-changed-to-keywords-in-python-3)

Comment: Comparison is done with `==`.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Soory for the silly7 mistake!!!

Comment: @RemcoGerlich but I think <if a:>  works fine..

Comment: It does, but I thought you were trying to compare in the lines above that, maybe I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
True = False
```

`True` becomes `False`.. And when you do:

```
True = True
```

It's like writing:

```
True = False
```

If you want to make it the "original" `True` again, you should:

```
>>> True = not True # recall that you assigned False to True
>>> True
True
```

Comment: `del True` is a better way to delete the local variable named `True`, making the builtin one visible again.

Comment: how can we access the built-in True in python? It seems you are performing 'not' operation on the local variable 'True' from your answer...

Comment: @HiteshPaul It'll become the "built in" `True`.