# Why are 2 of the 6 built-in constants assignable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, constants

In the documentation on [built-in constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html) (excluding `site` constants) it's stated that:

> Note: The names `None`, `False`, `True` and `__debug__` cannot be reassigned (assignments to them, even as an attribute name, raise `SyntaxError`), so they can be considered “true” constants.

If I'm not mistaken, `True` and `False` became "true" contants in Python 3. (As also described in the duplicate.)

Question is, why aren't the other two (`Ellipsis`, `NotImplemented`) "true" contants? Is there a use case for re-assigning these (`numpy` with `Ellipsis` perhaps?) that has exempted them from this limitation?

Exacerbating my confusion, in the documentation for [standard library types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#the-null-object), both the `Ellipsis` and `NotImplemented` types are, behaviorally, identical to the `None` type. Namely:

- They are singletons
- They don't support special operations.

---

This question is not related to the proposed duplicate: [Why were True and False changed to keywords in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050815/why-were-true-and-false-changed-to-keywords-in-python-3). It asks something completely different, namely, why `Ellipsis` and `NotImplemented` *are not "true" constants* and *not* why `True` and `False` where changed into ones.

Comment: So here's my opinion: there is definitely no use case for overwriting **any** builtin object. Any such code should be treated as dangerous. On the other hand making them all keywords would make it harder to maintain (on the C side). So I guess its a matter of the evolution of Python. Also `None`, `False` and `True` are used all the time so there's a special focus on them.

Comment: Funny enough, `Ellipsis = 2` is alright, but `... = 2` raises `SyntaxError: can't assign to Ellipsis`.

Comment: @freakish That is one opinion. Granted that Python likes simplicitly (especially after simplifying things in the transition to Python 3) I can't see how the extra complexity of maintaining only 2 other names trumps the uniformity of the contants behaving the same. That's why I thought there must be some use-case.

Comment: @Rightleg `...` is not syntactically valid as a name, afaik, names can't start with a `.`.

Comment: @BobHolver Why do you think there are only 2 other names? For example there are dozens builtin functions: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Comment: @freakish built-in constants is what this question is about.

Comment: @BobHolver There are no constants in Python sensu stricto. There are only constant keywords. And how are they different from builtin functions? Is it ok to overwrite for example `abs`?

Comment: [Python Built-in Constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html)

Comment: @BobHolver I know that, but when you try to write `.a = 1`, you get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Here it explicitly mentions `Ellipsis`.

Comment: @AChampion It's just a word they used in docs that doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @freakish A built-in function is clearly different from a constant; and really it is the docs to define the language spec

Comment: @freakish words mean something or we wouldn't be able to communicate. Constants are not [`keywords`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) (`as`, `in`, `for`, etc.), which you cannot reassign. Constants are not [built-in `functions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) (`abs()`, `min()`, `max()`, etc.), which you can reassign (bad form!!). Python treats some built-in constants as special. Fair question from the OP.

Comment: @AChampion You are wrong. `True`, `False` and `None` are **keywords** in Python3+. That's why it's a **SyntaxError** when trying to assign to them. There is no concept of constantness in Python. It's a meaningless word in Python.

Comment: @freakish sorry we will just have to disagree, they are constants because the language defines them as being constants, as in `a = True` is meaningful, vs `a = if` which is meaningless.

Comment: @AChampion Lol, it's not a matter of disagreeing. I'm talking about **facts**, here's a proof: https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=keywords#keywords For Python3+ `True = 1` **is meaningless**.

Comment: @freakish those are just words and don't mean anything - or you would also accept: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/constants.html, `a = True` is meaningful as in `True` has a value - in fact a constant value.

Comment: @AChampion No, these are not only words. There's a well defined and documented meaning and behaviour behind the word `keyword` unlike the word `constant`. Especially since these are not constants as some of them can be overwritten as pointed out by OP. It's a semantic inconsitency. I don't know why did you ignore docs about keywords.

Comment: @freakish let me refine one of my earlier statements, some (built-in) constants are defined as keywords. Constants have values so can be used in expressions and RHS of assignment statements, they are distinct from other keywords that cannot be used in expressions. I'm not ignoring the documentation. Hopefully, this refinement just points out that things can be constants and keywords both defined in the documentation - neither ignored.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why were True and False changed to keywords in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050815/why-were-true-and-false-changed-to-keywords-in-python-3)

Comment: @AChampion Show me a piece of Python docs defining what `constant` means and how it should behave. Otherwise you are only saying what you think constant should mean. I might even agree with you. But AFAIK it's not the case.

Answer (score 6):

You can assign to any valid identifier that is not a keyword. What is special about `True`, `False`, `None` is that they are *both* keywords and identifiers. You can read about the reasoning for that in this question:

[Why were True and False changed to keywords in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050815/why-were-true-and-false-changed-to-keywords-in-python-3)

Builtins such as `NotImplemented` or `Ellipsis` are not special cases, and neither are `int`, `list`, `type` and so on. Assigning to `NotImplemented` doesn't change the builtin constant. Instead you bind the name `Ellipsis` to a different value in the current scope. The original `Ellipsis` is not changed.

Assigning to a keyword is a SyntaxError.

You can see the list of keywords by importing the `keywords` module.

```
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.kwlist

['False',
 'None',
 'True',
 'and',
 'as',
 'assert',
 'break',
 'class',
 'continue',
 'def',
 'del',
 'elif',
 'else',
 'except',
 'finally',
 'for',
 'from',
 'global',
 'if',
 'import',
 'in',
 'is',
 'lambda',
 'nonlocal',
 'not',
 'or',
 'pass',
 'raise',
 'return',
 'try',
 'while',
 'with',
 'yield']
```

There are lots of builtin identifiers that are not in this list, and you can assign new values to `int`, `Ellipsis` etc.

`...` is a special case, since it's not a valid identifier name in the first place, so it would be impossible to assign to.

Python keeps the list of reserved keywords quite short, compared to many other languages. One reason is probably to keep backwards compatibility with code that for some reason used identifiers such as `Ellipsis` before it became part of the language.

Comment: I understand that assigning to keywords is not allowed. The question isn't about why it is an error to assign to `True`, rather, it's why `Ellipsis` and `NotImplemented` are specified as "constants" when they are assignable. Backwards compatibility is an issue, of course, but the transition from 2 to 3 would allow such a change, as was done with `True` and `False`.

Comment: The original builtin constant is unchanged, even if you assign the name to some other value in the current scope.

Comment: Yes, I understand how binding works too. This still does not answer *why* you can re-bind (assign to) the aforementioned names.

Comment: Because there's nothing special about those names. There just like any other non-keyword identifier in Python.

Comment: @BobHolver: You can consider `True` and `False` to have changed from constants to boolean literals.

Comment: @BobHolver I think your answer is in the last paragraph - "Python keeps the list of reserved keywords quite short". Things are only made into keywords when there is a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: As one case where adding keywords to the language broke existing code, the tensorflow library [used to have a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51996163/12299000) with an argument named `async`, which is a keyword in more recent versions of Python.