# Tensorflow `Syntax Error: pywrap_tensorflow` After Install

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, syntax-error

I've setup a virtualenv and using pip installed tensorflow via `sudo pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.10.0-py3-none-any.whl`.

However, when I open a python shell to test the install I get the following error:

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 26 2018, 23:26:24)
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/joshuablew/Projects/Environments/proj1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/Users/joshuablew/Projects/Environments/proj1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Users/joshuablew/Projects/Environments/proj1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Users/joshuablew/Projects/Environments/proj1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 114
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've searched around but can't find a straightforward solution to this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` is a reserved keyword in Python 3 ([here's the full list](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords)).

Look like you aren't the only one running into  this problem, there's an active thread on the `tensorflow` github issue tracker addressing it that dates back to July: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20517

Comment: Interesting, so should I try using a different version of tensorflow to get around this?

Comment: There's a PR in review right now. You'll have to either pull the code yourself or wait for a new release (hopefully soon? This is a pretty big issue). Here's the comment on the thread that addresses it: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20517#issuecomment-414037701

Comment: Alright, I hope it gets resolved soon too. Thanks for the help