# Python Certain Keywords Seem to be Usable as Variable Names

Tags: python, python-3.x

I stumbled into an interesting phenomenon with Python (3.7.6). I'd like to preface by saying that naming variables like this is a terrible idea that one should never do. However, the following code amazingly compiles:

```
list = (123, "abc", 222, "foo", "bar", 333); #Tuple named list
print(list);
```

However:

```
list = (123, "abc", 222, "foo", "bar", 333);
list = list(list);
print(list);
```

Raises a type error as tuples are not callable, and presumably it believes you are trying to call the tuple instead of cast the tuple to a list.

Of course, by changing the variable name like follows:

```
a = (123, "abc", 222, "foo", "bar", 333);
a = list(a);
print(a);
```

One is able to successfully cast a tuple to a list. It appears that this behavior exists for several different keywords. However, for some keywords this behavior is not seen such as with from. Can anyone explain this madness?  Specfically, what keywords can  be used as variables like this, and why is this even permitted in the first place?

Comment: None of those are key-words. By *definition* keywords cannot be used as variable names. You can get a list of keywords for your current python version using `import keyword; print(keyword.kwlist)` Anyway, `list` is merely the name of a built-in function, and like any other variable, it can be re-assigned, although, it is highly inadvisable to do so. Examples of keywords are things like `class`, `in`, `for` etc, usually parts of statements.

Comment: As an aside, and this is totally an aside, the word "cast" I think, isn't a useful way of thinking about these things in Python. You are passing a `tuple` object to the `list` object constructor, this constructor creates a *new list object* out of that `tuple`, because the `list` constructor takes any arbitrary iterable. The word *cast* comes with various erroneous (in Python) implications from lower-level, statically typed languages like C and C++. But I understand that "cast" is just used loosely to mean "convert"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are 2 of the 6 built-in constants assignable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44972211/12299000)

Answer (score 1):

`list` is a built-in function. It is not a keyword.
The whole keywords list can be seen here - [Python Keywords](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_keywords.asp)

Keywords can not be used as a variable name nor any object name.
But built-in function names can be re-defined as you said.

The common mixed usage is `id`. For example,

```py
def getTableFromDatabase(id):
    print ( id(dbname) ) # error, cos id is not a function
    return getTable(dbname, id)

t = getTableFromDatabase(1)
```

, where `id` is used for the id of a table. But `id` is one of the built-in functions. It is used for getting the hash id of an object.
The better practice is to use append underscores in front of such keywords.

```py
def getTableFromDatabase(_id):
    print( id(dbname) ) # prints id of dbname variable
    return getTable(dbname, _id)

t = getTableFromDatabase(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`list` isn't a [python keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords). Its an object (specifically a type object) bound to `builtins.list` which is used as a fallback in all modules. When you assign the `list` variable in your namespace, you mask the orignal type object. The type object is still available in `builtins`

```
>>> import builtins
>>> list = "foo"
>>> list("bar")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>> builtins.list("bar")
['b', 'a', 'r']
```

And you can always get it back

```
>>> list=builtins.list
>>> list("bar")
['b', 'a', 'r']
```

But best to avoid messing with those types. `dir(builtins)` will tell you what to avoid.