# What really is a keyword in Python?

Tags: python, object, keyword

We can get a list of Python keywords as follows:

```
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.kwlist
['False', 'None', 'True', 'and', 'as', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def', 'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'finally', 'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 'in', 'is', 'lambda', 'nonlocal', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'raise', 'return', 'try', 'while', 'with', 'yield']
```

Cool, but I didn't expect to see `False`, `None`, and `True` there. They are builtin objects.

Why are `True`, `False`, and `None` keywords, but `int` isn't? What really makes something a keyword in Python?

Edit: I am talking about Python 3

Comment: why would you expect `int` in there? If python had explicit typing, sure, maybe there'd be an `int` keyword, but in python `int()` is a function.

Comment: The Python version matters here.

Comment: Perhaps there is some confusion here because one might mistakenly think of keywords as "words that can't be used in an expression where an identifier would usually go". This accurately describes 99% of keywords -- for example, `2 + def` is not legal syntax. But False, None, and True _can_ be used in expressions, so they seem to break the rule. But the truth is, there is no such rule. If a keyword represents an object, then you can use it like an object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keywords are reserved names, so you can't assign to them.

```
>>> True = 0
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to keyword
```

`int` is a type; it's perfectly possible to reassign it:

```
>>> int = str
>>>
```

(I really wouldn't recommend this, though.)

Comment: Worth noting that in Python 2 where True is not a keyword, that first snippet works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Python isn't like Javascript. In Javascript, you can do things like `undefined = "defined"` (update: this has been fixed).

Keywords depend on which python you use. Ex: `async` is a new keyword in `3.7`.

Things haven't always been that way though, in Python 2 `True = False` was valid...

```
>>> True = False
>>> True
False
>>> True is False
True
```

So "They are builtin objects.", yes, but new versions of python prevent you from being stupid. This is the only reason why...

New keywords (since Python 2.7) are :

```
False
None
True
async
await
nonlocal
```

and of course `exec` and `print` aren't keywords anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Actually keywords are predefined, reserved names in Python that have *special meaning* for language's parser. Sometime they declare that we're about to define:

1. An instance of a type (like what `def` and `class` keywords does)
2. Condition statement (like `if`, `while` ...)
3. ...
4. Some times they are actual objects like `True`, `False`, `None`.

Because I see no body mentioned, we have two types of keywords: (*Examples are from python 3.10*)

1- Hard keywords: (`keyword.kwlist`)

```
['False', 'None', 'True', 'and', 'as', 'assert', 'async', 'await', 'break',
 'class', 'continue', 'def', 'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'finally',
 'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 'in', 'is', 'lambda', 'nonlocal',
 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'raise', 'return', 'try', 'while', 'with', 'yield']
```

2- Soft keywords: (`keyword.softkwlist`)

```
['_', 'case', 'match']
```

You can not use hard keywords as a variable name or assign something to them. They are reserved names in all places. But you can have a variable called `match` and also you can have them inside an expression as a normal variable. `match` is only have special meaning if it is in the first line of a match-case block.

From [PEP 634](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/):

> Remember that *match* and *case* are soft keywords, i.e. they are not
> reserved words in other grammatical contexts (including at the start
> of a line if there is no colon where expected).

Answer (score 0):

in python 2.6 you could do something like True = False (really confusing)

It may help you this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050815/why-were-true-and-false-changed-to-keywords-in-python-3)